# Export map to JPG file using python?

Tags: arcpy, export, windows, jpg

I don't know if this question fit to this site but i will try: i want to export maps to JPG files with this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\PROJECTS\bneyBrakZafonMegorim\gis"
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxd 
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\PROJECTS\bneyBrakZafonMegorim\gis\\" + mxd)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc, r"G:\PROJECTS\bneyBrakZafonMegorim\gis\out\\"+os.path.basename(mapdoc.filePath).replace ('.mxd','') +".jpg",resolution=120)
    print 'ExportToJPEG'
    mapdoc.save()
del mxd
```

Now, the code worked fine till this morning- the maps exported to JPG files but the date and the date time of the export action didn't changed into the accurate time (today) in the windows (7 professional) operation system. This is my date time now:

[image]

and when i export the map i get this date time in the windows operation system:

[image]

Comment: There is no date/time in your code. Is there a dynamic text element in your MXD?  If so, see what date/time that is currently showing.

Comment: PolyGeo, i added another explanation now.